# magento 2 how add new tab to layered navigation?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, tabs

I need some help. I add new category with layered navigation and I have all product from my base on this page. How we can add new tab to layered navigation with some options like "free products" and "sale". I hope for your help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this answer will help someone.

I make plugin after `function geFilters()` in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList.`

And add to result array my filter like:

```
$result [] = $this->objectManager->create('MyModule\Block\Model\Layer\Filter\MyFilters', ['layer' => $this->layer]);
```

For the layer you need `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver` object. And MyFilters file I make like `Price.php` in catalog-seach.